# All ArUo Tags are getting Rejected when passing the image data from Unity

Tags: c++, opencv, unity-game-engine, dll, aruco

**Background**

I am trying to detect ArUco markers from image data sent from Unity to  OpenCV Functions which are accessed using their .dlls.

**Versions**

OpenCV : 4.5.0/4.5.1
Unity : 2020.1.17f1
Aruco dictionary : 6x6_250 family and AprilTags 36h11 family

**Problem**

When I use a camera and send each frame(as shown in code here), `detectMarkers()` function works but every tag gets rejected.

I have tried:

- Flipping the image only in Unity using `System.Array.Reverse(rawImg)`     *  I have also tried flipping the image in c++ using `flip(imageCopy,  imageCopy, -1)` and then back after the image is processed;

- In a combination of both in Unity and OpenCV. But I made sure the image which was feeding into `detectMarkers()` function was proper(i.e not flipped) by 'imshow()`.

- I have also changed from aruCo dictionary to April tags so that there is no version mismatch in the tags.
- I also checked by loading the image using `imread()` only in .dll. This works and the tag gets detected.
- In addition, I also tried sending single image data (using Texture2D as image type). Here the Unity crashes during the `cvtColor()` line.

**Part of the Unity code snippet**

`private WebCamTexture CamTexture;`

```
 void Start()
 {
   CamTexture = new WebCamTexture();
   CamTexture.Play();
 }

 void Update()
 {
   if (CamTexture.isPlaying)
     {
       var rawImg = CamTexture.GetPixels32();
       MarkersDetection.detectAruco(ref ArucoID, ref arrayLength, ref rawImg, WebcamWidth, WebcamHeight);
     }
}
```

**Part of OpenCV code snippet**

```
struct Color32
{
    uchar red;
    uchar green;
    uchar blue;
    uchar alpha;
};

extern "C" void __declspec(dllexport) __stdcall detectAruco(int& outArucoID,int& arraySize,Color32 **rawImg,int width,int height) {
cv::Mat imageCopy;
cv::Mat image(height, width, CV_8UC4, *rawImg);

cvtColor(image, imageCopy, COLOR_BGRA2BGR); 
cv::aruco::detectMarkers(imageCopy, arucoDictionary, arucoCorners, arucoIds, parameters, rejectedCandidates);
}
```

Comment: Can you `imshow` the image after transferring it from Unity to .dll? The problem could be in the `cvtColor`. If I am not mistaken, Unity handles pixels in ARGB (or RGBA) layout, not BGRA. This could potentially confuse the aruco detection.

Comment: Thank you.yes imshow works .i displayed it before conversion.Here it does not look right. Definitely needs conversion) and after cvtColor it looks normal like a webcam.And you are right Unity gives RGBA.But still the tags are getting rejected.

Comment: So if the `rawImg` coming from Unity is in RGBA format, your `image` is assigning every red channel to blue channel (since opencv operates on BGRA format by default). This means essentially you are swapping the actual values in red and blue channels. If this is the case, writing `cvtColor(image, imageCopy, COLOR_RGBA2BGR);` should fix the issue.

Comment: Yes , I thought the same too and changed the conversion to COLOR_RGBA2BGR.But it still doesnt work :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was doing the flipping wrong! Now I flipped the image using a image tool(any editing tool which flips image works; rather than manually) and now it works.